# Detecting Class of an object implementing an interface

Tags: java, class, implements

I'm writing a game, as part of this players should be able to click on various GUI items and see further details on a specific area of the GUI.  I'm mangaing this through an interface `Detailable` which is implemented by suitable game obects and sends the appropriate information to the `JPanel`

There are also containers (all of which implement `Detailable`) that contain other (`Detailable` implementing) objects.  The goal being it is possible to click on a container and, amongst its stats, see its contents which can then be in turn clicked on to see *their* stats, etc.

The problem I am having is in writing the `addToContents(Detailable d)` method of my containers.  Each container as an `ArrayList<String>` of the "type" of container - wardrobe, bookcase, etc.  I want to be able to add only certain classes to a given container - so a container with a type of "bookcase" will only accept objects of class `Book` or `Curio` for example.

What I currently have is:

```
public boolean addToContents(Detailable d){
        if(this.types.contains("bookcase") && d.getClass().getName().equals("Book")){
            //do some stuff
            //I know "Book" isn't the right syntax, this is just to demo
            return true;
        }
        else if(this.types.contains("bookcase") && d.getClass().getName().equals("Curio")){
            //other stuff
            return true;
        }
        //etc
        else{
             return false;
        }
    }
```

But this feels like the wrong way of doing it.  Is there a better way?  Ideally, for sake of easy code, I'd have something like (pseudocode)

```
Constructor:
private ArrayList<Class> classesAccepted = <list of classes>

addToContents:
if (classesAccepted.contains(d.getClass()){
    add the thingie to contents
    return true
}
else{
     return false;
}
```

but I can't seem to find a way of adding a list of classes to the constructor - of translating the ArrayList of class names to an ArrayList  of references to the actual class.

---

Containers are currently read from a JSON so comprise two classes:

```
public class FurnitureType {
    private String name;
    private List<String> type;
    private int cost;
    private String description;
    private int comfortBonus;
    private int capacity;
    //plus getters for all the above
}

public class Furniture implements Detailable, ListSelectionListener{

private String name;
private List<String> types;
private int cost;
private String description;
private int comfortBonus;
private int capacity;
private ArrayList<Detailable> contents;
private transient DetailPanel dp = null;

public Furniture (FurnitureType type){
    this.name=type.getName();
    this.types = type.getType();
    this.cost = type.getCost();
    this.description = type.getDescription();
    this.comfortBonus = type.getComfortBonus();
    this.capacity = type.getCapacity();
    this.contents = new ArrayList();
}
//appropriate getters

public boolean addToContents(Detailable d){
        if(this.types.contains("bookcase") && d.getClass().getName().equals("Book")){
            //do some stuff
            //I know "Book" isn't the right syntax, this is just to demo
            return true;
        }
        else if(this.types.contains("bookcase") && d.getClass().getName().equals("Curio")){
            //other stuff
            return true;
        }
        //etc
        else{
             return false;
        }
    }
@Override
public String toString(){
    return description;
}

@Override
public Icon getBigPic() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public JComponent getStats() {
    Object [] objectContents = contents.toArray();
    JList contentList = new JList(objectContents);
    contentList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400, 300));
    contentList.setFixedCellHeight(50);
    contentList.addListSelectionListener(this);
    contentList.setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
    //the CustomCellRenderer class simply makes long descriptions into multiline cells
    return contentList;
}

@Override
public void addPanel(DetailPanel dp) {
    this.dp = dp;
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
    Detailable d = contents.get(lse.getFirstIndex());
    dp.updatePanel(d);
}
```

Comment: You are almost there in your pseudo code right? what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, will update the question for clarity - you're right I haven't made the problem particularly explicit

Comment: Does Book and Curio have a common supertype?

Comment: They don't, but they could have if that's an easier solution.  Neither currently extends anything

Comment: Can you show us how your current containers look like ?

Comment: Why do not use instanceof or isAssignable ?

Comment: Also you can have a set of acceptable classes and check does it contain object class or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
ArrayList <Class<? extends Detailable>> acceptedClasses = new ArrayList<>();

acceptedClasses.add(Bookcase.class);
acceptedClasses.add(OtherAcceptable.class);
```

and then do something akin to

```
boolean test = 
    acceptedClasses.stream().anyMatch(clazz -> aClass.isInstance(detailableInstance));
```

to check if the instance is of an acceptable type

Comment: Simply `new ArrayList<>()` should be fine in Java 7+

Comment: Federico, I should really have ran that though an compiler first. Thanks for pointing it out, fixed the class vs. clazz typo and dealt with the boolean problem as well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use a `Map` as shown below:

```
private static Map<String, List<Class<? extends Detailable>>>
       bookcaseContainer = new HashMap<>();

 static {
       //load the bookcaseContainer Map from properties/database
         bookcaseContainer.put("bookcase", list1);
         bookcaseContainer.put("wardrobe", list2);
    }


if(bookcaseContainer.get("bookcase") != null && 
        bookcaseContainer.get("bookcase").contains(d.getClass())) {
        //do something here
 } else if(bookcaseContainer.get("wardrobe") != null && 
        bookcaseContainer.get("wardrobe").contains(d.getClass())) {
        //do something here
 }
```

Comment: Good answer and thanks for all the help.  Accepted the other as the code is slightly shorter and I can't accept two, but its a nice solution.